# xmlstarlet - need to selectively replace attribute value based on value of another attribute

Tags: xmlstarlet

Just wondering if anyone can help me.
I'm currently building a pfsense firewall, which uses VPN connections to secure the traffic.
The VPN provider does provide a port forwarding mechanism, but the incoming port number changes every hour. I have a script which allows me to discover the new port, but I need a scripted way to modify the port forward settings in the firewall to match.

A snippet of the firewall config file that controls this is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pfsense>
  <nat>
                <rule>
                        <source>
                                <any/>
                        </source>
                        <destination>
                                <any/>
                                <port>53400</port>
                        </destination>
                        <protocol>tcp/udp</protocol>
                        <target>192.168.0.15</target>
                        <local-port>53400</local-port>
                        <interface>opt2</interface>
                        <descr><![CDATA[Torrent]]></descr>
                        <associated-rule-id>nat_52d81d2dc904f5.77023355</associated-rule-id>
                        <created>
                                <time>1389894957</time>
                                <username>admin@192.168.0.20</username>
                        </created>
                        <updated>
                                <time>1389980696</time>
                                <username>admin@192.168.0.20</username>
                        </updated>
                </rule>
  </nat>

  <filter>
                <rule>
                        <id/>
                        <type>pass</type>
                        <interface>opt2</interface>
                        <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
                        <tag/>
                        <tagged/>
                        <max/>
                        <max-src-nodes/>
                        <max-src-conn/>
                        <max-src-states/>
                        <statetimeout/>
                        <statetype>keep state</statetype>
                        <os/>
                        <protocol>tcp/udp</protocol>
                        <source>
                                <any/>
                        </source>
                        <destination>
                                <address>192.168.0.15</address>
                                <port>53400</port>
                        </destination>
                        <log/>
                        <descr><![CDATA[NAT Torrent]]></descr>
                        <associated-rule-id>nat_52d81d2dc904f5.77023355</associated-rule-id>
                        <created>
                                <time>1389894957</time>
                                <username>NAT Port Forward</username>
                        </created>
                        <updated>
                                <time>1389899075</time>
                                <username>admin@192.168.0.20</username>
                        </updated>
               </rule>
  </filter>
</pfsense>
```

In the XML above, we have the two parts which comprise a port forward rule for pfsense. The part enclosed in the `<nat>` section is the port forward. The section in the `<rule>` is an interface specific incoming firewall rule. Both have to be modified for the new port forward setting to be effective.

I was thinking to use xmlstarlet to modify the config file, using the `<descr>` as my key for identifying which sections to change.

I'm aware that you can have data like:

```
<username><![CDATA[name]]></username>
<password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
<dbname><![CDATA[name]]></dbname>
```

and modify it with:

```
xml ed -P -O -L \
  -u '//username/text()' -v 'something' \
  -u '//password/text()' -v 'somethingelse' \
  -u '//dbname/text()' -v 'somethingdifferent' file.xml
```

and also that you can have something like:

```
<objects>
 <object>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <constant1>10</constant1>
    <constant2>20</constant2>
  </object>
  <object>
    <name>Bar</name>
    <constant1>15</constant1>
    <constant2>40</constant2>
  </object>
<objects>
```

and update attributes with:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//object[name="Foo"]/const1' -v 18 sample.xml
```

However, I'm struggling to merge the two, so that I have a single statement which matches `<descr>="Torrent"` and then updates the relevant `<port>` and `<local-port>` attributes.

Any help with a suitable xmlstarlet command would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is using multiple statements unacceptable?

Comment: Not at all. It's going to be in a bash/sh script, so it doesn't matter how many statements it takes to achieve the desired result. I'll just be happy to get a method that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -u '//rule[descr="Torrent"]/destination/port' -v 1111 \
  -u '//rule[descr="Torrent"]/local-port' -v 2222 \
  sample.xml
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That works perfectly. My mistake was to not include the /destination bit. I just didn't notice it.